# how could i edit Admob adunit size from banner to interstitial?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, admob, interstitial

i just found out myself helpless when i changed the ad type in my app from banner to          `interstitial`. But i used the same `ad-banner` id from admob. though the interstitial are appearing just fine, my ecpm is quite low....

i tried to edit admob adunit type from `banner` to `interstitial` for my app but it is disabled under my `app setting` tab.

so do i have to create a new `adunit id` for my app and post the `new version` of my application in the `App Store` with updated ad unit id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - yes.

You need separate AdunitIds for banner and interstitial. They pull from different pools of available advertising.

They are also presented differently on the client. You need to use different APIs to present interstitials than banners. See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced

Comment: thanx for the response. i wish admob allowed changing ad unit type from their website. that way i dont need to upload my app again to appstore just for changing that ad unit id

Comment: But there is a huge difference between banners and interstitials. Interstitials require careful thought about how they fit into your application flow.